# the a tag content goes to a new line

Tags: html, css

This is a Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/67QR8/

I have a ul class `main_menu` and in one of its `li`, I have a ul class `sub_menu`

the `a` tag in the `main_menu` expand to fit the `a` content, but the `a` tag in the `sub_menu` doesn't.

why please?

#### What I have tried

I added width 200px to the li in the `sub_menu` like this

```
.header ul.sub_menu li{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

and it works, but that is, in my opinion, just a workaround rather than a solution. I would like to know why is that happening and how to fix that without setting a specific width. because it works in the first `a` tag so it should work in the second `a` tag.

many thanks

#### Update 1

I've made the background red just in order to show you which `ul` i am taking about

Comment: Add `white-space: nowrap` to `.header ul.main_menu li a`. Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/67QR8/1/) what you need? Doing this essentially instructs the browser not to wrap around by default. But you should either add a `width` or `overflow:hidden` to make sure it doesn't go too wide.

Comment: @Harry yes you right, I forgot about `white space` property. thanks. type an answer to accept it. and please why it works without the `while space` in the first `a` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, solution to the problem is to add the below setting to the CSS. As mentioned in my earlier comment, this instructs the browser not to wrap around by default.

```
.header ul.sub_menu li a{ 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Note:** It is not required to be added to `ul.main_menu li a` because it would then apply to all anchor tags that are present within an `li` under the `main_menu` including the main menu's items (and since we are not using `>` it would apply to the sub menu's `li a` which are not direct children of main_menu also).

Coming to the question on why the `a` tag within the sub_menu is getting wrapped around while the one in main_menu doesn't, it is because of the submenu's `li` tag being the child of an absolutely positioned element. Check out [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732127/the-width-of-div-with-absolute-position-depends-on-its-parents-width) for a beautiful explanation on the topic.

> **Extract:**
>   The element gets its width and height before it gets removed from the flow of the document. When you position the outside element absolutely, it gets removed from the flow and since it has no immediate content, it has a width of 0 and height of 0. Therefore, another division element inside it attempting to add text inherits the parent's width of 0. So it's only going to expand to the width of the longest word to allow for content, and then break everything else to new lines. After it's done that, it removes the element from the flow of the document to be off on its own.

In the code relating to this question, here the element took the width of "Functions" or "Locations" as the maximum width (both almost same width) and got wrapped around.